# How to use the Postgres overlap (&&) operator on array

Tags: postgresql

I was doing a `contains` operation on Postgres (9.6.2) like this and it works:

```
SELECT *
FROM "store"
WHERE "store"."items_json" @> '{"content":{"type":{"category":[{"size":"xxl"}]}}}';
```

Then I tried with an `overlap` operation

```
SELECT *
FROM "store"
WHERE "store"."items_json" && '{"content":{"type":{"category":[{"size":"xxl"}]}}}';
```

but I got

`ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb && unknown`

Does anyone have a hint on how to fix this?

This works fine:

```
SELECT ARRAY[1,4,3] && ARRAY[2,1];
```

Comment: There isn't any `&&` operator  for jsonb fields. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html

Comment: `'{"content":{"type":{"category":[{"size":"xxl"}]}}}'` is not an  array literal it's a json object

Comment: @McNets you're right, please make it an answer so I can accept. I assumed if @> and <@ were operators, && would work. I was wrong.